# ValueError: Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, quantization, quantization-aware-training

After a long search for my problem, any solution fund won’t work for me. I hope that you can help me to overcome this problem so I can continue my project.
The problem is while doing post-training integer quantization of a GRU model, it gives me the following error :
**ValueError: Failed to parse the model: pybind11::init(): factory function returned nullptr.**
[GRU quantization error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez6xE.png)

the code I am using :

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(GRUMODEL_TF)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
def representative_dataset_gen():
for sample in XX_data:
    sample = np.expand_dims(sample.astype(np.float32), axis=0)
    yield [sample]

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8
converter.representative_dataset = repr_data_gen
model_tflite = converter.convert()
open(GRUMODEL_TFLITE, "wb").write(model_tflite)
```

Comment: Could you file a bug in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow?

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution? Could you share it?
I think it might have to do with the data_generator. But I have not yet been able to confirm/solve it.